Importing a .pyx file into Python on VSCode
I'm running a Jupyter notebook window on VSCode using Python 3.10.11. I'm trying to import a .pyx file, so that I can use the functions defined in it, using
import pyximport
pyximport.install()
from function_file import function_1

I get a long error but there seems to be two key parts:
CompileError: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.39.33519\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

ImportError: Building module function_file failed: ["distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\\\2022\\\\BuildTools\\\\VC\\\\Tools\\\\MSVC\\\\14.39.33519\\\\bin\\\\HostX86\\\\x64\\\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2\n"]


better show FULL error message.

error shows cl.exe which (as I remeber) is part of C/C++ compiler and it may need to install C/C++ compiler and maybe also install some extra C/C++ libraries - but all this have to do manually because it is not part of Python.
